# Deleting File that isn't in the Form, but is in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am showing a list of uploaded files from ~/Content/Files and also giving the user the option to Upload. I am trying to place a Delete button next to each File and allow it to just be "seamlessly" deleted, and have it removed from the page. I'm not sure if the fact that I have a Form on the page and I'm not using that form in the post is causing me confusion as well.

Aside from the seamlessly deleted piece, here's what I have :

#### View

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

<h2>Files</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var fName in Model)
    {
        var name = fName;
        var link = @Url.Content("~/Content/Files/") + name.Replace(" ", "%20");

        <li style="margin: 10px;">
            <a href="@link">@name</a> | <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Home", new { fileName = name })'">
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Files", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="File" name="file" id="file" value="Choose File" />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    }
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteFile(string fileName)
    {

        string file = fileName;
        string fullPath = Request.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + file);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Files");
    }
```

Here's the `Files` Action method if you care to know :

```
public ActionResult Files()
        {
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/");

            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            var files = dir.EnumerateFiles().Select(f => f.Name);

            return View(files);
        }
```

It keeps trying to route me to `http://localhost:51123/Home/DeleteFile?fileName=test.docx` (and I understand that's because of the button `onclick` method), when all I want to do is execute the Delete method and then reload the View.

I'm sure I am going wrong in a few different places.

Comment: You are sending a GET request (the link) hoping to match a POST action. You need to wrap up the delete button in its own form and do a normal submit.

Comment: @MikeSW Thanks, it took me a while to realize the query string was the result of a GET and the Method was a POST =(. If you want to throw that as an answer I'll upvote + accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the request as a `GET` request and your action method in your controller has the `[HTTPPost]` attribute decorating the method. This will only allow `POST` request to enter this action method. You have a few options. You can change the request to a `POST` request and the request will successfully find the correct action method in the controller. Another option is that you remove the `HTTPPost` attribute decorating your action method in your controller.

Personally, I would suggest changing the request to an Http `DELETE` verb (since that is the intended action of the request) and then decorating your method with the `HTTPDelete` attribute.

**UPDATE:**

To submit this request as a HTTP DELETE you can do something like the following by changing what your onclick event will do:

```
<li style="margin: 10px;">
            <a href="@link">@name</a> | <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteRecord(name)">
        </li>
```

And in your javascript you will have a function like this:

```
function DeleteRecord(name) {

$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Home")',
   data: name
   type: 'DELETE',
   success: function(response) {
     //...
   }
});
}
```

The reason I do it through jQuery's ajax function is because HTML forms (up to HTML version 4 and XHTML 1) only support GET and POST as HTTP request methods. A workaround for this is to tunnel other methods through POST by using a hidden form field which is read by the server and the request dispatched accordingly.

However, GET, POST, PUT and DELETE are supported by the implementations of XMLHttpRequest (i.e. AJAX calls) in all the major web browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari).

Cheers!

Comment: If this were to be changed to an `[HttpDelete]` it looks like a couple things would have to be changed since there is no simple overload for `@Url.Action` to include a `Delete`

Comment: Whoops I put the wrong Type in the .ajax  function. Should have been type: 'DELETE'. I have updated it.

Answer (score -1):

Your files action is getting files from Content/Files.  Your delete action is trying to delete files in Content/Images.  You need to use the same folder in both actions for the changes to show up.